# Receiving error while creating project with Razor page template

Tags: visual-studio-2019, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

Immediately I click on create and the project loads. I always receive the below error. I cannot do anything without correcting this.

This is the error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   NETSDK1004  Assets file 'C:\Users\HARBIORLAR PC\Desktop\VB Web Projects\BookList\BookList\BookList\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.   BookList    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    234

Screen shot of the error:

[image: screen shot of the error]

Comment: Did you try the Nuget package restore as it recommends?

Comment: I do not know how to do Nuget package restore @halfer can you help me on how to go about it

Comment: Neither do I - but I am sure you can research it `:-)`. Start with reading the documentation - can your app be packaged into this system?

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did and it works,I Enable automatic package restore by choosing Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager, and then selecting Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio under Package Restore.
Then I build the project with internet connection on and the missing file was downloaded.
[This the Screen shot After successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUQdg.png)